# I use \n for a new line inside arrays. But it didn't work. (python)

Tags: python-3.x

why doesn't \n work in arrays?
Here, the \n does not create a newline. Python makes \n as a string. the result, the words don't create a new line down. i actually know, we can use "Print".But i'm just curious. This is my code: (Thank you)

```
def Europe():

    country = [
       "England\nFrance\nGermany",
       "Poland\nSpain\nItaly",
       "Finland\nSweden\nNorway"
    ]

print(country)
```

Europe()

Comment: your code syntax is incorrect, you have different strings in a list but they are not separated by comma. You are missing a closing ".  Your indentation is wrong (content inside a function must be indented). And your formatting if also wrong, leaving the call to Europe outside the code formatting block. Please fix your code

Comment: You failed to call your function
Europe().
A for loop would have done a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason Python does not interpret \n when you print an array as a whole, so you must iterate through all the elements. Also fixed some syntax errors.

```
def Europe():
    
    country = [
        "England\nFrance\nGermany",
        "Poland\nSpain\nItaly",
        "Finland\nSweden\nNorway"]

    for countries in country:
        print(countries)

Europe()
```

Comment: thanks sir, this is very helpful. Thank you. I'm learning a lot now

Comment: That "some reason" would be that printing a list *prints a valid Python representation of the list*, which basically outputs your original source code again. In contrast to that, printing a string prints the string "contents", the "visible part" of it, not a source code representation of it.